# swipe to delete in tableview not triggering

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have these 3 delegate methods implemented for my swipe to delete handling, but nothing is happening and none of these methods get called.

```
//returns UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

//removes deleted object from my tabledata array
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

//checks if data actually can be deleted (all set to yes currently)
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

what exactly am i missing?  im swiping all day long on my table cells but nothing happens.

Comment: You're 1000% sure you've assigned this class as the tables delegate right?

Comment: i am 1000% i sure have

Comment: Please put your header file in so we can see if delegate was assigned. If you did it in code please confirm

Comment: What method did you put your delegate in? Have you registered any other touch events?

Comment: Found the problem, allow multiselect was activated, and apparently that cancels out any swipe detection

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the **DataSource** & **Delegate** connected up to your view controller 
and also make sure you refresh the table when done using `[self.tableView reloadData];`